# joint density random variables with a set of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, ordinary-differential-equations

There are $n$ equations: $f_i(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,e_i)=0$, $i$ from $1$ to $n$, where $e_i$ are independent random variables whose expectations are all $0$. $x_i$ are random variables. Suppose the map $e \rightarrow x$ can be inverted, here $e$ and $x$ are vectors of $e_i$ and $x_i$ respectively.

Prove that the joint density $p(x)=p(e)|det(\frac{de}{dx})|$, where det is the determinant on the matrix $de/dx$, or represent $p(x)$ by $p(e_i)$ and $de_i/dx_i$.

Thank you!